# Multiple order-by, when one value is a priority option (high,moderate,low)?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to order my posts:

1. Firstly, by `Post.priority` ‘High’, ‘moderate’, ‘low’
2. Secondly, by `Post.date_posted`

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.priority.desc(),Post.date_posted.desc()).all()
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

**forms.py** (high, moderate and low are selected as drop down options in the HTML template)

```
priority_options = [('moderate', 'moderate'),('high', 'high'),('low','low')]
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description',[validators.Required()])
    date_posted  = DateField('Date',format='%Y-%m-%d',default=datetime.now()+ timedelta(hours=1))
    time_posted  = TimeField('Time',format='%H:%M',default=datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1))
    date_closed  = DateField('Date',format='%Y-%m-%d')
    time_closed  = TimeField('Time',format='%H:%M')
    priority = SelectField('Priority',choices = priority_options)
    assigned_to = StringField('Assigned To')
    reported_by = StringField('Reported By')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**db model:**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.utcnow)
    time_posted = db.Column(db.Time, default=datetime.utcnow)
    date_closed = db.Column(db.Date)
    time_closed = db.Column(db.Time)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    priority = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    assigned_to = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    reported_by = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

Thank you

Comment: If you indeed need to have a solution for alphanumeric ordering, one solution would be to have a separate lookup table for `Priority` with columns `name: str` and `sort_order: int`. In your query you would then make a join and order by `Priority.sort_order.desc()`. Alternatively, you can just sort items on the python side before redering.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually stated your problem, but I'm guessing you would like the `Post.priority.desc()` to match the semantic meaning of the priority and not the actual string.

At the moment you're storing priority as a string so `Post.priority.desc()` would be:

1. moderate
2. low
3. high

`M` is bigger then `L`, which is bigger then `H`.  You want it to be :

1. high
2. moderate
3. low

The easiest solution is to store your priority as a number, then in your templates etc, resolve that number to a text-representation.